# When install app from play store was crashed in android version 11 but old versions work fine

Tags: flutter

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: packageid, PID: 12639
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageid/packageid.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3521)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:285)